# Sharepoint Aggregate lists

Tags: sharepoint, list, aggregate

I'm trying to aggregate results from different list types. Using Join feature in Sharepoint designer won't cut it. What I want to achieve is eq. to in T-SQL "Select x AS y".

For example - The column "Title" doesn't exist in one list type but the column "Name" does.
What I want to do is as I would in SQL: "Select Name as Title"
I've tried looking into CAML but no luck there.

Much appreciated

V

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this using the Camelot .NET Connector for SharePoint, available at http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/

When using it you may question your SharePoint lists and document libraries as if they where ordinary SQL tables.

Ie.

```
SELECT LinkTitle as Title, CreatedDate as `Created Date`, ID as `List item id` FROM WhatEverListYouLike WHERE ID > 10
```

There are also predefined functions to handle most common operations of documents like FileUpload and FileDownload. These are covered in the documentation - http://docs.bendsoft.com/camelot-net-connector/latest/procedures/

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but that one is a bit expensive for the purpose.